# object HTMLUnknownElement

Tags: javascript

Доброго вам времени суток! Есть проблема, вот код :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./system/scc.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="system/connect/config/js/moveWin.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getAttributes(node) {  
    var ret         = new Object();  
    if(node.attributes)  
    for(var i=0; i<node.attributes.length; i++) {  
        var attr    = node.attributes[i];  
        ret[attr.name]  = attr.value;  
    }  
    return ret;  
}
//
function loadXML(xml) {
    var divlib          =   document.getElementById('xd');
    var divid           =   document.getElementById('ldh');
    divlib.innerHTML    =   xml;
    var c1              =   divlib.getElementsByTagName('wins');
    var c2              =   c1.item(0).getElementsByTagName('win');
    for (var i=0;i<c2.length;i++) {
        var elex        =   document.createElement('div');
        var atr         =   getAttributes(c2.item(i));
        elex.id         =   atr.id;
        elex.style.left =   atr.left;
        elex.style.top  =   atr.top;
        elex.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {

            }, false);
        elex.className  =   'moveDiv';
        elex.innerHTML  =   'xdd'+i;
        document.body.appendChild(elex);
    }
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.moveDiv {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #CCC;
    border-top-width: 10px;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-top-color: #000;
    border-right-color: #000;
    border-bottom-color: #000;
    border-left-color: #000;
    height: 300px;
    width: 100px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="xd" style="display:none;"></div>
<div id="ldh"></div><br />
<input type="button" onclick="presetLoader('./x.xml');" value="load" />
</body>
</html>
```

При активации данной строчки **alert(document.getElementById(this.id));** (клик по слою) алерт сообщает следующее : **object HTMLUnknownElement** , решается это так : 
**elex.id         =   atr.id+'abcdef';** тоесть путём добавления буквы/букв в конец, но мне это не удобно, и нужно без этих букв.
Данные получаются из xml файла, код :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wins counts="2">
<win id="win_allWidgets" left="200px" top="40px"></win>
<win id="win_chat" left="100px" top="100px"></win>
</wins>
```

За загрузку отвечает функция :

```
var toTpath;
function presetLoader(toTpath) {
    use4connect         =   getXmlHttp();
    use4connect.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (use4connect.readyState == 4) {
            if (use4connect.status == 200){
                sth     =   '';
            } else {
            if (use4connect.status != 200){
                return(false);
            } else {
                return(false);
            }
            }
            if(use4connect.status == 200) {
                loadXML(use4connect.responseText);
            }
        }
    }
    use4connect.open('GET', toTpath, true);
    use4connect.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    use4connect.send(null);
}
```

Подскажите правильный код, или как преобразовать в "правильную" строчку значения полученные из xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена. Дело было в том, что в содержимое слоя записывался xml документ, а он и содержал элементы с подобными идентификатороми, после создания новых слоёв, слой который содержал данные xml - очищался и всё встало на свои места.